# How does the Void-Touched Sorcerer bloodline arcana work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, bloodline

The Bloodline Arcana for a [Void-Touched Sorcerer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo---sorcerer-archetypes/wildblooded/mutated-bloodlines---paizo/void-touched) reads as follows:

> Whenever you cast an evocation spell, you may select one affected target that fails its save to suffer the choking airlessness of the void, silencing it (as silence, but affecting only the target) for 1 round. This is a supernatural ability.
>
> This ability replaces the Starsoul Bloodline Arcana.

If this arcana is used with magic missile (an evocation spell), which has no saving throw, does the silence feature do anything?

The current assumption is that the evocation spell being used must have a saving throw in order for any possible failure to occur, to trigger silence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The assumption's correct... and it's even worse than that

For the [sorcerer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer)'s [void-touched bloodline arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo---sorcerer-archetypes/wildblooded/mutated-bloodlines---paizo/void-touched) to take effect, the sorcerer must cast a spell from the evocation school *both* that has as its target one or more creatures *and* that mandates making a saving throw. (A generous GM may waive the first restriction so that such a sorcerer has a chance of silencing one creature *affected* by—despite not being the *target* of—, for example, the spell [*fireball*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) as the number of higher-level spells of the evocation school that *target* foes is very small.)

Thus, for example, the spells [*ear-piercing scream*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/ear-piercing-scream) and [*touch of combustion*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/touch-of-combustion) combine with the void-touched bloodline arcana, but, for example, the spells [*burning hands*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burning-hands) and [*flare burst*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/flare-burst) don't combine with the bloodline arcana as they don't have targets, and the spells [*magic missile*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-missile), [*shocking grasp*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp) and [*thunderstomp*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/thunderstomp) don't combine with the bloodline arcana as they don't mandate saving throws

Answer (score 2):

There was no save, so nobody failed it.

Thus, nobody qualifies to be selected and the arcana, just as you postulated, does nothing.

That still holds true if you use an Evocation spell with a save, but nobody fails it.